# Create a jquery function independent of a click event and run in on load of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to abstract my javascript/jquery code in order to avoid repetition of it. I have a click event, which is executed when the user selects a value from a dropdown menu:

```
$(".dropdown-menu-methods li a").click(function(){
  $("#button-methods:first-child").text($(this).text());
  $("#button-methods:first-child").val($(this).text());
  selected_val = $(this).attr("id");
  element_id = ["_panel_container", "_panel_msg"];
  clear_content(element_id);
  if (selected_val == "excel_layer"){
    $("#_panel_container").append('<i>"Choose an existing layer </i>);
    ...
```

This function is executed on button click but I would like to be able to execute it anytime by passing a variable to it. 
How can I do something like this? Detach the functionality from a click event and execute it on page load?

Comment: i suggest use `change` event than `click` you can call the change event manually if you want to run it on load something like `$('#selectid').change()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a standard JS function and call it from wherever and whenever you want:

```
function theFunc() {
    // do stuff
}


$(".dropdown-menu-methods li a").click(function() {
    theFunc();
});
```

`theFunc()` is a standard JS function and can be passed as many arguments as you want

Comment: You can also pass the function reference as`$(".dropdown-menu-methods li a").click(theFunc)`

Comment: Seeing the OP's example code, @Satpal's version is even needed, for `this` to have the proper context inside the function.